# QueryDSL NumberPath/SimplePath mixup on x64/x86

Tags: java, jpa, ant, querydsl

We are having this weird problem (or maybe we are missing some parameter configuration) that if we compile our project using a x86 JVM everything works OK, but if we use a x64 JVM we get this error during compilation:

```
QT_LOG.java:66: incompatible types
found   : com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath<java.lang.Long>
required: com.mysema.query.types.path.SimplePath<java.lang.Long>
public final SimplePath<Long> id = _super.id;
```

This behavior happens if we use ANT as described in here: 
http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.4.3/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e147

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines,vars"        
fork="yes" executable="...x86...or...x64...JAVAC" classpathref="My Project.classpath"
source="1.6" target="1.6" encoding="iso-8859-1" >

<compilerarg value="-proc:only"/>      
    <compilerarg value="-processor"/>
    <compilerarg value="com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"/>
    <compilerarg value="-s"/>
    <compilerarg value="c:/myPath/"/>

    <src path="${mySourceFolder}" />
</javac>
```

If we use Eclipse, we also get the different values (NumberPath/SimplePath) but we don't get any error.

What can we do to fix this?

Tested with QueryDSL 3.2.3 and 3.4.3.

Comment: Could you create an issue for it here https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues

Comment: Did you managed to validate this behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate it.

Comment: As requested, just created the issue: 
https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in querydsl-jpa-?.?.?-apt-hibernate-one-jar.jar since I removed all dependencies to it and added references to the following individual jars:

QueryDSL 3.2.3

```
codegen-0.6.0.jar

hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar

hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar

hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar

hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar

javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar

javax.persistence-2.0.4.v201112161009.jar

jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar

mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar

querydsl-apt-3.2.4.jar

querydsl-codegen-3.2.4.jar

querydsl-core-3.2.4.jar

querydsl-jpa-3.2.4-apt.jar

querydsl-jpa-3.2.4.jar

querydsl-sql-3.2.4.jar
```

QueryDSL 3.4.3

```
codegen-0.6.3.jar

hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar

hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar

hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar

hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar

javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar

javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar

jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar

mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar

querydsl-apt-3.4.3.jar

querydsl-codegen-3.4.3.jar

querydsl-core-3.4.3.jar

querydsl-jpa-3.4.3-apt.jar

querydsl-jpa-3.4.3.jar

querydsl-sql-3.4.3.jar
```

and everything compiles correctly now